# How to get fileName from uri?

Tags: android, android-intent, uri, filenames

I got some uri, that looks something like this
content://media/internal/audio/media/48
I got it from intent, but I want to get the file name of the file it point to. How can I do this ?

Comment: I found the solution Ringtone r=RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, uri);
and than the name is taken like this r.getTitle(this));

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution

```
Ringtone r=RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, uri);
```

and than the name is taken like this

```
r.getTitle(this));
```

Answer (score 4):

If I understood you right, I would try create a new File object with File aFile = new File(uri) and then call getName() on aFile.

edit: or try it like this:

```
File aFile = new File(uri);
if(aFile.isDirectory())
{
aFile.list()
}
else
{
aFile.getName()
}
```

list() would give you a stringarray of the contained files...

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code...

```
File objFile = new File(File_Path);
objFile.getName();
```

Comment: This just returns the last path segment and not the file name. Link to File class documentation: [File.getName()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getName%28%29)